# What is the Linux 64 Assembly Equivalent for C's system call?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

(Question edited, thanks to @fuz)

*What is the Linux 64 Assembly Equivalent for C's system call?*

I want to write assembly that essentially has the same function as calling the CLI in C, such as `system("ls -l")`.

The code I want to reproduce has essentially the same function as the following C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   system("ls -l");

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The `system` function is not a system call.  It is a library traditionally implemented in terms of `fork`, `execve`, and `wait`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit my question accordingly!

Comment: Now that you've removed the part of the question about doing it with a raw system call, the obvious answer is to simply `call system` with a pointer in RDI.  You don't have to reimplement libc functions, you can just call them, assuming you link your program with libc.

Answer (score 4):

The `system` libc function is *not* a kernel system call.  That's why its man page is [`system(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) not `system(2)`.

It's implemented on top of fork(2) + execve(2), and the `waitpid(2)` system calls.  In fact that's the first thing the `system(3)` man page says!  Go read it, just like you should read the Linux man page for any actual system call or library function you want to know about.

Use `strace` on a program that calls it, or single-step into it with GDB, or read the glibc source code.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified my question!